# Compute $\int_0^1 \frac{\exp(u^3 - 4/3 u) du }{\sqrt {1 - u^2}} $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function

Compute the integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\exp(u^3 - 4/3 u) du }{\sqrt {1 - u^2}} $$

I assume contour integration is the easier way ?

Comment: it concerns me that WA can't find an answer for the general antiderivative in terms of any functions it knows...perhaps the definite integral is easier. Mathematica gives the answer as being about 1.039034250753441

Comment: how exactly would you employ contour integration?

Comment: What is the source of this problem if you don't mind me asking?